# unresolved R.id in android

Tags: android

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but for some reason the Line R.id.action_search remains unresolved even though I have defined it in the menu/main.xml

here is the MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //... other methods above
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        //handle each number from the item in a case block
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_search: //error on this R.id call. Unresolved
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in the main.xml file:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />"
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    </menu>
```

Is there anything that I did wrong? Is there a way that I am supposed to define my id's?

Comment: Do *not* import `android.R`. Use `android.R.id.action_search` when referencing system ids, and use `R.` only for your own project's ids, then `import com.example.myfirstapp.R`

Comment: Clean your project: Project->Clean. Take a look in your gen folder - is R.java in there? If not, it is not rebuilding as it should, most likely because you have an error in one of your layout xml files.

Answer (score 1):

My SDK had me convert the switch/case structure to an if/else if/else one.  It's weird that it worked for me after that.

```
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.action_search) {
        openSearch();
        return true;
    } else if (itemId == R.id.action_settings) {
        openSettings();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be importing your project's R.java. Try that

Comment: I was told that if I import Android that it would confuse the compiler in terms of which R file to use (either Android.R or R in my package file). Is that not true?

Comment: Android R is not in your package, compiler won't have an issue to compile. import your package and when you want to use android R file, you can just use it by calling android.R

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code. Generally you should keep your menu related items in menu under res folder.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
// If it in menu folder then use R.menu.main and if it in layout then use R.menu.main

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your generated R class isn't generated, it indicates that there's a problem with generating it due to some parsing issue from the XML resources. Check the error console in your IDE to figure out what's specifically wrong.

Common problems are:

- An unescaped character in your `strings.xml`, for instance `you're` instead of `you\'re`
- Missing `layout_width` or `layout_height` tags in layout resources
- Missing namespace declarations
- Variable names that aren't supported by Java, for instance due to capitalization or use of spaces, hyphens or other unsupported characters
- Any other kind of syntax error in XML
- Check **Console** and **Problem** Tab, you will found your error, when you resolve te error and build your project again so your **R.Java** will be generate.